# Low noise high voltage gain amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, analog, power-electronics, filter

I have a very small voltage output in microvoltage range. I want to amplify it to atleast milivolt. So a voltage gain of 10^4 is required.
Can anyone suggest any suitable amplifier for that?

Comment: What is the source? In other words, which part of the electrical signal carries the information? That can be: charge, voltage, current, or their derivatives or integrals.

Comment: What kind of signal? Frequency ...

Comment: Source impedance, desired bandwidth, operating temperature range, and dynamic range of the input signal are starting questions...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Something like https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8429.html